# Set text to custom title page pivot

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've created pivot page and I wish to display in the 2 text blocks at the top some information. I've created DataTemplate and set x:names for text fields. But I can't adress from page constructor to this text blocks and put there text. Why? And how can I cheat this situation? I need to put to text blocks information while page are loading.

```
        <controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_eventID" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_eventName"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Opacity="0.7"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using a DataTemplate is to define the presentation of a business object. That is to say that if you have a class like the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string StringOne { get; set; }
    public string StringTwo { get; set; }
}
```

If you set the Title property of your Pivot control to an instance of this class, a DataTemplate can be used to define what you want it to look like.

In your case, the template could look like this:

```
    <controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringTwo}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Opacity="0.7"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

Then from the code-behind, you would set the Title property of the Pivot control. Something like this:

```
 myPivotControl.Title = new MyClass 
     { 
         StringOne = "Some String", 
         StringTwo = "Some other string" 
     };
```

---

There is another way you could do this, which would allow you to simply set the text boxes from the code behind, but this does not involve a DataTemplate.

Setting the Title property of your Pivot control like the following, will enable you to access the TextBox's by name:

```
    <controls:Pivot.Title>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_eventID" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_eventName"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Opacity="0.7"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:Pivot.Title>
```

[Read this article for more on DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903947%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I knew how to use DataTemplate, but didn't understand how to apply them to the page