# Windows Phone 8.1 Pivot custom header style

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm aiming to mimic similar effect as seen here: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/05/23/Changing-the-background-color-of-your-pivot-headers.aspx .
There are resources online describing how to do it, but all of them apply to Windows Phone 8. 8.1 update brought severe API changes, making the code useless.

So, how can I style pivot header? I found namespace [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.aspx), which includes class PivotHeaderPanel, which might be helpful in this situation, but I can't find a way to access this class from XAML.
Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: I don't really think the 8 to 8.1 changes would effect style templates that much. Either way you should be able to dig around in the style templates as much as you want, right click->Edit additional templates-> find the title or header template, otherwise could just look at the defaults and pick out which part you want to manipulate. In other words I think the only real difference is now you you'd set a template for like <control:Pivot.Title>'s content

Comment: I tried it. But for some reason, Blend only lets me add a blank template. And it's literally blank: inside DataTemplate there's only <Grid/>. This happens both in my project and in newly created Pivot app template.

Comment: Ah right, I haven't personally tinkered with it yet, but maybe now it's [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.primitives.pivotheaderscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.105).aspx) for the pivot header control

Comment: Well, the thing is, I can define header like this: http://pastebin.com/32kmKc0H . But this way I can't reach the effect I showed in the link above.

Comment: [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.aspx)   -_- , progect Sirverlite or Runrime? http://c2n.me/iK7IeA

Comment: @IceFog, I have seen the page. I linked to it after all. My project uses Windows Runtime, not Silverlight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207197/pivot-item-header-wont-change-to-custom-font/25208407#25208407 my post

Comment: @IceFog, it doesn't work. Compiler complains that "primitives:" is not defined and that "PivotHeaderItem is not supported in Windows Phone project".

Comment: How exactly do you want to style the header? In the link you provided, the post simply talks about changing the background color of the headers.

Comment: @eggplant there writes before code (without primitives:) http://c2n.me/iKgCkr

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to change the background color of all the headers, this is how you can do it in Window Phone 8.1.

First, use Expression Blend to generate the default style of the `Pivot` control.

```
<Thickness x:Key="PivotPortraitThemePadding">19,38,0,0</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="PivotLandscapeThemePadding">19,25,0,0</Thickness>
<Style x:Key="CustomPivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                        <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                            </PivotHeaderPanel>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
                                <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ItemsPresenter>
                        </PivotPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Find this line below, the only change I have made to the default style is adding `Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"` to the `PivotHeaderPanel` which is the panel that hosts all the headers.

```
<PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
```

The reason that I use `TemplateBinding` here is because doing this gives me the flexibility to change the headers background by specifying the `BorderBush` of the `Pivot`. As the `BorderBrush` is not used anywhere in the control, there won't be any side effect if we change it.

So, all you need to do in your `Pivot` is this.

```
<Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" Style="{StaticResource CustomPivotStyle}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
```

This is how they look now.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

So 8.1 killed how I used to do HeaderTemplates.

My solution now is to put a customized TextBlock or Control in the Header element of the PivotItem.

---

```
<Pivot>

    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="WHY DID YOU DO THIS MICROSOFT"/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem.Header>
    </PivotItem>
    ...
</Pivot>
```

Comment: yeah, I figured it out on my own before, but it looks just terrible.
Out of curiosity, how are you trying to get answers internally?

Comment: i work there (y) lots of pain at this time about a lot of the 8.1 api

Comment: I see. Has the API gotten any better since 8.1 Update 1?

Comment: Haven't been able to upgrade :) errors edit: oh the api, no clue, not on that team