# How to set different Selected/Unselected Pivote header color for Multiple Pivot

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1

I have below code in my App.xaml to override pivot item header color

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>                
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="#CACACA"/>                    
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="#D81B60"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush"  Color="Transparent" />
                <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="Assets/Profile.png"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>                
             <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <ImageBrush x:Key="HubBackgroundImageBrush" ImageSource="{x:Null}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>                
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

i want to set differernt PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush for different Pivot
 e.g
 Pivote1 ->pivoteItem1 -> PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush should be RED

Pivote1 ->pivoteItem2 -> PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush should be RED

Pivote2 ->pivoteItem1 -> PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush should be GREEN

Pivote2 ->pivoteItem2 -> PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush should be GREEN

I tried to override this color theme in Page but it is not working

if i set below style to pivote it changes color but for both Selected and unselected , it there any way to do this for only selected

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PivotHeaderSelectedTemplate">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                   Text="{Binding}" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                   FontStyle="Normal"
                   FontSize="44" 
                   Foreground="#630083"/>            
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle"
           TargetType="Pivot">            
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource PivotHeaderSelectedTemplate}"/>            
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Silverlight or XAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it for a specific Pivot, only application-wide. It's a bug. You might be able to change it in code, though. See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/19abb732-4f23-40b4-9ba5-215def6f01e7/how-to-change-the-colour-of-a-pivot-header-text-in-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: The only way to differentiate the selected and unselected colors is to override the `PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush` and `PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush` resources in your application's resource dictionary, as you did. You can't override these resources per-pivot. It just won't work.

Comment: hi Decade Moon, i have updated my question do you have suggestion on it?

Comment: See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26974421/734040) I did yesterday for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to override values of resources from App.xml through c# code runtime?

Comment: Yes, you can access the resource dictionary through `Application.Current.Resources` and theme resources through `Application.Current.Resources.ThemeDictionaries`. You would have to dynamically change the resources on page enter/exit so that pivot headers on different pages will get different colors.