# Getting rid of strange margin above pivot in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, templates, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have very frustrating problem. I have an WP8.1 app (WinRT - Universal) in which I use pivot control and above it I have search button (screen here: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2r5s13d.jpg ). Search button is in Grid.Column 0 and Pivot is in Grid.Column 1, but I have this strange margin (marked on screen) which I can't get rid of and it covers my search button (only half of it is active). My Grid.Column 1 and pivot should start on line closer to the word "TEST" and theoretically it is, but the second line (higher one) which shouldn't be there, it's there, it's empty but it's prohibit search button to be tapped. In header template I have a following code:

```
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="20" Margin="0,3,0,0" FontWeight="Normal"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try add Margin inside Pivot Control etc. Margin="0,-20,0,0" and add pivot control behind from search button for you can tap this.

Comment: I can't do margin thing because it's lowering my stuff inside pivot item, and search button should be on top of pivot

Comment: you try something like this ?

<Pivot>
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  FontSize="20" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

    <PivotItem Header="my pivot item" />
    
</Pivot>

Comment: This original answer is here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25339839/734040.

This margin is here For Pivot title propery. Change style and remove TitleContentControl , maybe this work.